# How to start writing UWP apps with React Native?

Tags: react-native, win-universal-app

So there was this big announcement that you can now [write Windows apps using React Native](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/).

The announcement links to a [Github page](https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native) which in turn leads to some description on [how to install React Windows](https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native/tree/ReactWindows/ReactWindows)

After spending a few hours installing Visual Studio and dependencies, SDKs and whatnot, I've got this "ReactNative" solution built in Visual Studio but I still can't figure out how to even start writing a simple *Hello World* program.

All the documentation points to how to write Android or iOS programs in Visual Studio Code, but there's no indication on how to write a UWP program.

Does anyone know where to start? What is the Visual Studio equivalent of "react-native init"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you've run `react-native init AwesomeProject`…

```
cd AwesomeProject
npm i --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows
react-native windows
```

This will generate the Visual Studio solution for your project and the `index.windows.js` entry point. Visual Studio Code is a great tool for editing React Native JavaScript.

To run your app just run `react-native run-windows`.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no out-of-the-box solution released for UWP Apps with React Native. The only known App with UWP support currently is the F8App, there is a [blog post](https://ericroz.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/f8-app-on-windows-10-mobile/) about how they ported it.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the answer is at the command line you do "react-native init" - you don't do it through Visual Studio. 
See https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows#getting-started

The Visual Studio project creates a UWP project which knows how to load and run react-native js code. The VS code is just a wrapper basically.

To start off a new react native project on windows, open the command line ad do the following:

```
REM This is the same on Mac or Windows..
react-native init AwesomeProject 

cd AwesomeProject

REM You need to install the react package manager
npm install -g rnpm

REM Add the rnpm-plugin-windows into your package.json
npm install --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows

REM This will create a "windows" folder in your project folder, 
REM the eqivalent of the ios and android folders.
rnpm windows

REM You will now have a windows folder with a AwesomeProject.sln file
REM You need to start the packager which projects the Javascript bundle to the runtime

react-native start

REM Open the solution in VS and run it, and you will see your app!
```